# How get a copy of edited excel without saving original one

Tags: c#, excel

I have excel file and make few changes in it but not saved. Now i want to create new excel file which is copy of existing with included changes. Please suggest how can i copy an excel without save it.

Answer (score 1):

if its c# try

```
Workbook.SaveAs(@"c:\file.xls")
```

see here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
this.SaveCopyAs(@"C:\work\copy.xlsx");
```